# Mongoose - finding subdocuments by criteria

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've just got stuck with this problem. I've got two Mongoose schemas:

```
var childrenSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    age: {
        type: Number,
        min: 0
    }
});

var parentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name : {
        type: String
    },
    children: [childrenSchema]
});
```

Question is, how to fetch all subdocuments (in this case, `childrenSchema` objects) from every parent document? Let's suppose I have some data:

```
var parents = [
    { name: "John Smith",
    children: [
        { name: "Peter", age: 2 }, { name: "Margaret", age: 20 }
    ]},
    { name: "Another Smith",
    children: [
        { name: "Martha", age: 10 }, { name: "John", age: 22 }
    ]}
];
```

I would like to retrieve - in a single query - all children older than 18. Is it possible? Every answer will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you want it to only return the parent if the child is over 18 or do you want it to only populate the children that are over 18 on each parent?

Comment: It would be great if I get the set of "children"...

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use `$elemMatch` as a query-projection operator in the most recent MongoDB versions. From the mongo shell:

```
db.parents.find(
    {'children.age': {$gte: 18}},
    {children:{$elemMatch:{age: {$gte: 18}}}})
```

This filters younger children's documents out of the `children` array:

```
{ "_id" : ..., "children" : [ { "name" : "Margaret", "age" : 20 } ] }
{ "_id" : ..., "children" : [ { "name" : "John", "age" : 22 } ] }
```

As you can see, children are still grouped inside their parent documents. MongoDB queries return documents from collections. You can use the aggregation framework's `$unwind` method to split them into separate documents:

```
> db.parents.aggregate({
    $match: {'children.age': {$gte: 18}}
}, {
    $unwind: '$children'
}, {
    $match: {'children.age': {$gte: 18}}
}, {
    $project: {
        name: '$children.name',
        age:'$children.age'
    }
})
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51a7bf04dacca8ba98434eb5"),
            "name" : "Margaret",
            "age" : 20
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51a7bf04dacca8ba98434eb6"),
            "name" : "John",
            "age" : 22
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I repeat the `$match` clause for performance: the first time through it eliminates parents with **no** children at least 18 years old, so the `$unwind` only considers useful documents. The second `$match` removes `$unwind` output that doesn't match, and the `$project` hoists children's info from subdocuments to the top level.

Comment: It works! :) Thanks for help! :) Where can I get some docs about advanced MongoDB operations? Its docs are enough? I wish to learn as much as possible about MongoDB :)

Comment: Take 10gen's online MongoDB For Developers class, read Rick Copeland's MongoDB Design Patterns book.

Comment: I know, i'm quite late, but what if a parent have more than one children over 18? I tried the first query on mongo shell, but it only retrieves one match for each parent. Am I right?

Comment: Thanks!@A.JesseJiryuDavis I have one more question about it, I saw the results only contain "_id" of parent object, what could I do if I want keep all parent's data and only with children over 18, like:
{ "_id" : ..., "name": "John Smith", "children" : [ { "name" : "Margaret", "age" : 20 } ] }

Comment: For those who end up here and are frustrated with this answer like I was... It can be done just using find. Here's an example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/qfAskjZcNGz
I got there from this question, though it's specifically mentioning nesting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229123/return-only-matched-sub-document-elements-within-a-nested-array

Answer (score 23):

In Mongoose, you can also use the elegant [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) function like this:

```
parents
.find({})
.populate({
  path: 'children',
  match: { age: { $gte: 18 }},
  select: 'name age -_id'
})
.exec()
```

Comment: `populate` works when referencing documents in other collections. The OP is using sub docs.

Comment: It is a long time since I made this answer :) & I can't try it now, but I think it should work also for embedded docs!

Comment: If it does not match returns `null`

Comment: @AbdelHady it wont work for embedded documents, `populate` only works for referenced documents

Comment: Not relevant for the question, and could lead to confusion and bugs been introduced to peoples code - as this examines multiple collections.

Answer (score 1):

A. Jesse Jiryu Davis's response works like a charm, however for later versions of Mongoose (Mongoose 5.x) we get the error:

Mongoose 5.x disallows passing a spread of operators to `Model.aggregate()`. Instead of `Model.aggregate({ $match }, { $skip })`, do `Model.aggregate([{ $match }, { $skip }])`

So the code would simply now be:

```
> db.parents.aggregate([{
    $match: {'children.age': {$gte: 18}}
}, {
    $unwind: '$children'
}, {
    $match: {'children.age': {$gte: 18}}
}, {
    $project: {
        name: '$children.name',
        age:'$children.age'
    }
}])
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51a7bf04dacca8ba98434eb5"),
            "name" : "Margaret",
            "age" : 20
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51a7bf04dacca8ba98434eb6"),
            "name" : "John",
            "age" : 22
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

(note the array brackets around the queries)

Hope this helps someone!