# Return a subdocument based on one of it's properties using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using mongoose, I want to search for subdocuments that have a certain property and return the most recent one.

```
// the relevant part of the user schema
id: String,
__history__: {
    reply: []
}

// the components of a 'reply' (not defined by a schema)
id: String,
createdAt: Date,
props {
    tipID: String
}
```

Given a specific **user** `id`, I want to search their `reply[]`s for replies that **have** a `tipID` in their `props`. I then want to return the `tipID` for the `reply` that has the most recent `createdAt`.

I'm new to - well - coding in general. Would love any pointers on how best to tackle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $elemMatch was returning an error (I think because reply wasn't a proper schema defined doc), I got the following to work instead.

```
User.findOne("_id": user._id}, function (err, doc) {
    var replies = doc.__history__.reply;
    for ( var i = 0; i < replies.length; i++ ) {
        if (replies[i].props.hasOwnProperty("tipId")) {
            // do something
            break; // stop because i only wanted the first hit
    }
}
```

Note: I didn't have to worry about sorting by time because `__history__.reply` items were already ordered by most recent first.

Comment: Just a code note for readability, you could've done i = 0; i < replies.length; i++ and avoided creating a new variable replyCount.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate question of [Mongoose - finding subdocuments by criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845191/mongoose-finding-subdocuments-by-criteria)

For your specific question, the trick with mongoose subdocuments is twofold:

a) avoid nesting within subdocuments if you can, i.e. *do not nest your attributes within `propId`* rather put those attributes straight into the reply, whatever they may be.

b) use `$elemMatch` as suggested in the duplicate answer I quoted above.  This will make sure that mongoDb finds the right documents, since mongoDb recognises `{a:1,b:2}` and `{b:2,a:1}` as two different subdocuments.

Comment: I should have been more clear - the 'reply' isn't a schema defined subdocument.  Trying the $elemMatch approach return an error for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only finding one document, then organize the replies something like this..

```
// find your doc by ID
user.findOne({ id: id }, function(err, doc) {
    // sort replies by createdAt date
    var replies = _.sortBy(doc.reply, function(reply) {
        return reply.createdAt.getTime(); // convert to seconds from jan 1, 1970
    });

    return replies[0].props.tipId;
})
```

Comment: Accept the answer please?

Comment: it pointed me in the right direction but wasn't yet solving the problem - added in my solution as well. thanks for the help!