# Mongoose filter nested array in pre find query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following issue. I have some comments that are soft-deletable. So they have a flag `is_deleted` and it is set to true when a record is deleted.

My comments aren't an independent model, but they are a nested array in another model (simplified model):

```
let CommentSchema = new Schema({
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    modified_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: null
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    is_deleted: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
});

let BookSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    comments: [CommentSchema],
    ...
});
```

Now when I get all my Books with `Books.find({}, (err, books) => {})` I wanted to filter out the deleted comments in:

```
BookSchema.pre('find', function() {
    this.aggregate(
    {},
    { $unwind: '$comments'},
    { $match: {'comments.is_deleted': false}})
});
```

But it does not work. Any idea how to write the query, so that it only return the non-deleted nested comments without creating an independent Comment collection?

EDIT: I didn't mention it's an endpoint where I access only one book object. The resource url is like this: `/books/{bookId}/comments`. But also nice to have if it would work when getting all book objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [positional $ operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) and filter directly from find. As greatly explaned by @Blakes Seven [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229123/return-only-matched-sub-document-elements-within-a-nested-array)

```
BookSchema.find({
 'comments.is_deleted': false,
}, {
 'comments.$': 1,
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

As you said the `$ operator` only return one element, here is what the document says :

> The positional $ operator limits the contents of an  from the
>   query results to contain only the first element matching the query
>   document

There is two solution to your problem:

1. Make an aggregate, which is usually slow to get executed by database
2. Get the books and filter the comments using loops

---

```
BookSchema.find({
   'comments.is_deleted': false,
}).map(x => Object.assign(x, {
   comments: x.comments.filter(y => !y.is_deleted),
}));
```

The `find` get all books that have a non-deleted comment.

The map loop on each book.

We then remove the comments marked as deleted

Comment: It works (get's one comment) but I need to get all Book comments. Is there any way ?

Comment: I didn't mention one important thing. This is an endpoint where I have only one book object. The resource is accesed via: `/books/{bookId}/comments`. Sorry, I will update my post above.

Comment: Ok, I went with the map/filter solution. Works ok, but if somebody has a more *generic* solution I would be happy to see it. Thanks @Grégory NEUT :)!