# MongoDB query with elemMatch for nested array data and return only matching elements

Tags: arrays, mongodb

```
{
"_id" : NumberLong(107),
"cnic" : NumberLong(098765),
"recordsOFGt" : [ 
    {
        "records" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : NumberLong(1),
                "contactIds" : [ 
                    NumberLong(303)
                ],
            },
            {
                "_id" : NumberLong(2),
                "contactIds" : [ 
                    NumberLong(303),
                    NumberLong(304)
                ],
            },
            {
                "_id" : NumberLong(3),
                "contactIds" : [ 
                    NumberLong(309),
                    NumberLong(304)
                ],
            },
            {
                "_id" : NumberLong(4),
                "contactIds" : [ 
                    NumberLong(303),
                    NumberLong(304)
                ],
            },
            {
                "_id" : NumberLong(5),
                "contactIds" : [ 
                    NumberLong(303),
                    NumberLong(304)
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
    "records2" : {
     ...
     ...
    }
]
}
```

I want only record element that will be matched via `_id` I have tried this

```
db.getCollection('tempCollection').findOne(    
  { 'recordsOFGt': {$elemMatch: {'records._id': 1} }},
  {'recordsOFGt.$': 1}
)
```

this returns all elements of records array need just matching element.

this is what I want as output :

```
{

     "records" : 
          {
               "_id" : NumberLong(1),
               "contactIds" : [ 
                     NumberLong(303)
               ],
          }

}
```

Comment: can u put ur required response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return only matched sub-document elements within a nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229123/return-only-matched-sub-document-elements-within-a-nested-array)

Comment: you have ti use aggregration for this