# Return object from a list if it's child object contains a certain value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've been stuck on this issue for a while, I feel like I'm close but just can't to figure out the solution.

I have a condensed schema that look like this:

```
{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5a423f48d3983274668097f3"
        },
        "id": "59817",
        "key": "DW-15450",
        "changelog": {
            "histories": [
                {
                    "id": "449018",
                    "created": "2017-12-13T11:11:26.406+0000",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "field": "status",
                            "toString": "Released"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "448697",
                    "created": "2017-12-08T09:54:41.822+0000",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "field": "resolution",
                            "toString": "Fixed"
                        },
                        {
                            "field": "status",
                            "toString": "Completed"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "fields": {
            "issuetype": {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Bug"
            }
        }
    }
```

And I would like to grab all `changelog.histories` that have a `changelog.histories.items.toString` value of `Completed`.

Below is my pipeline

```
"pipeline" => [
[
    '$match' => [
        'changelog.histories.items.toString' => 'Completed'
    ]
],
[
    '$unwind' => '$changelog.histories'
],
[
    '$project' => [
        'changelog.histories' => [
            '$filter' => [
                'input' => '$changelog.histories.items',
                'as' => 'item',
                'cond' => [
                    '$eq' => [
                        '$$item.toString', 'Completed'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
]
```

So ideally I would like the following returned

```
{
"id": "448697",
"created": "2017-12-08T09:54:41.822+0000",
"items": [
    {
        "field": "resolution",
        "toString": "Fixed"
    },
    {
        "field": "status",
        "toString": "Completed"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return only matched sub-document elements within a nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229123/return-only-matched-sub-document-elements-within-a-nested-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
db.changeLogs.aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$changelog.histories' },
  { $match: {'changelog.histories.items.toString': 'Completed'} },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$changelog.histories" } }
]);
```

This solution performs a COLLSCAN, so it is expensive in case of a large collection. Should you have strict performance requirements, you can create an index as follows.

```
db.changeLogs.createIndex({'changelog.histories.items.toString': 1})
```

Then, in order to exploit the index, you have to change the query as follows.

```
db.changeLogs.aggregate([
  { $match: {'changelog.histories.items.toString': 'Completed'} },
  { $unwind: '$changelog.histories' },
  { $match: {'changelog.histories.items.toString': 'Completed'} },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$changelog.histories" } }
]);
```

The first stage filters the changeLog documents having **at least one history item** in the `Completed` state. This stage uses the index. The second stage unwinds the vector. The third stage filters again the unwound documents having at least one history item in the `Completed` state. Finally, the fourth stage replaces the root returning items as documents.

## Edit

Based on your comment, this is an alternate solution preserving `id` and `key` fields in the returned documents (while keeping using the index).

```
db.changeLogs.aggregate([
  { $match: {'changelog.histories.items.toString': 'Completed'} },
  { $unwind: '$changelog.histories' },
  { $match: {'changelog.histories.items.toString': 'Completed'} },
  { $project: { _id: 0, id: 1, key: 1, changelog: 1 }}
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and the the detailed explanation, I've had a play around and this looks interesting however I actually need to project (select) fields such as `id` and `key` which are fields that come before `changelog`, it this possible using `$replaceRoot`?

Comment: Edited answer in order to preserve `id` and `key` fields in the returned documents.

Comment: Thanks, this looks amazing, how does this work exactly, why the need to two `$match` statements?

Comment: Role of each $match stage is explained just after the query. I suggest you to execute query with only the first stage in the pipeline and look at the resulting documents. Then adding the second. Then the third... and so on. You will figure out the need for the second $match stage. Furthermore, consider that after unwinding the vector, any index on it cannot be used anymore.