# How to get matched sub documents by Geowithin from mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, geospatial

What I am trying to do here is that I want only those subdocument which is within the provided latitude and longitude but if only one subdocument inside my document matches and others do not it should only return me the document with that particular document. but it is returning me all subdocument too can someone you guys help me out.
my document is like this

```
{
         "_id": "5ae04fd45f104a5980cf7e0e",
          "name": "Rehan",
         "email": "rehan@gmail.com",
         "status": true,
         "created_at": "2018-04-25T09:52:20.266Z",
         "parking_space": [
             {
                 "_id": "5ae05dce5f104a5980cf7e0f",
                 "parking_name": "my space 1",
                 "restriction": "no",
                 "hourly_rate": "3",
                 "location": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        86.84470799999997,
                        42.7052881
                    ]
                },
            },
            {
                "_id": "5ae06d4d5f104a5980cf7e52",
                "parking_name": "my space 2",
                "restriction": "no",
                "hourly_rate": "6",
                "location": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        76.7786787,
                        30.7352527
                    ]
                },
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ae2f8148d51db4937b9df02",
        "name": "nellima",
        "email": "neel@gmail.com",
        "status": true,
        "created_at": "2018-04-27T10:14:44.598Z",
        "parking_space": [
            {

                "_id": "5ae2f89d8d51db4937b9df04",
               "parking_name": "my space 3",
                "restriction": "no",
                "hourly_rate": "60",
              "location": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        76.7786787,
                        30.7352527
                    ]
                },
            }
        ],
    },
   }
```

I am applying this query.

```
User.find({
        "parking_space.location": {
            "$geoWithin": {
                "$centerSphere": [
                    [76.7786787, 30.7352527], 7 / 3963.2
                ]
            }
        },
    }, function(err, park_places) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send({
                data: err,
                status: false
            });
        } else {
            return res.send({
                data: park_places,
                status: true,
                msg: "Parking data according to location"
            });
        }
    });
```

and i am trying to get data like this.

```
{
         "_id": "5ae04fd45f104a5980cf7e0e",
          "name": "Rehan",
         "email": "rehan@gmail.com",
         "status": true,
         "created_at": "2018-04-25T09:52:20.266Z",
         "parking_space": [
            {
                "_id": "5ae06d4d5f104a5980cf7e52",
                "parking_name": "my space 2",
                "restriction": "no",
                "hourly_rate": "6",
                "location": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        76.7786787,
                        30.7352527
                    ]
                },
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ae2f8148d51db4937b9df02",
        "name": "nellima",
        "email": "neel@gmail.com",
        "status": true,
        "created_at": "2018-04-27T10:14:44.598Z",
        "parking_space": [
            {

                "_id": "5ae2f89d8d51db4937b9df04",
               "parking_name": "my space 3",
                "restriction": "no",
                "hourly_rate": "60",
              "location": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        76.7786787,
                        30.7352527
                    ]
                },
            }
        ],
    },
   }
```

is it possible to get data like this.

Comment: Can someone help me out

Comment: Maybe this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229123/return-only-matched-sub-document-elements-within-a-nested-array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of what you are trying to do here, the far better option is to actually use the [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) aggregation pipeline stage to determine the "nearest" matches within your constraints instead. Notably your criteria actually asks for [`$geoWithin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) for a **7 mile radius** by the application of the math applied. So this really is better expressed using [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/), and it's options actually allow you to do what you want.

```
User.aggregate([
  { "$geoNear": {
    "near": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [76.7786787, 30.7352527]
    },
    "spherical": true,
    "distanceField": "distance",
    "distanceMultiplier": 0.000621371,
    "maxDistance": 7 * 1609.34,
    "includeLocs": "location"
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "parking_space": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$parking_space",
        "cond": {
          "$eq": ["$location", "$$this.location"]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
],function(err,park_places) {
  // rest of your code.
})
```

This would produce a result that looks like this:

```
{
        "_id" : "5ae04fd45f104a5980cf7e0e",
        "name" : "Rehan",
        "email" : "rehan@gmail.com",
        "status" : true,
        "created_at" : "2018-04-25T09:52:20.266Z",
        "parking_space" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "5ae06d4d5f104a5980cf7e52",
                        "parking_name" : "my space 2",
                        "restriction" : "no",
                        "hourly_rate" : "6",
                        "location" : {
                                "type" : "Point",
                                "coordinates" : [
                                        76.7786787,
                                        30.7352527
                                ]
                        }
                }
        ],
        "distance" : 0,
        "location" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [
                        76.7786787,
                        30.7352527
                ]
        }
}
{
        "_id" : "5ae2f8148d51db4937b9df02",
        "name" : "nellima",
        "email" : "neel@gmail.com",
        "status" : true,
        "created_at" : "2018-04-27T10:14:44.598Z",
        "parking_space" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "5ae2f89d8d51db4937b9df04",
                        "parking_name" : "my space 3",
                        "restriction" : "no",
                        "hourly_rate" : "60",
                        "location" : {
                                "type" : "Point",
                                "coordinates" : [
                                        76.7786787,
                                        30.7352527
                                ]
                        }
                }
        ],
        "distance" : 0,
        "location" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [
                        76.7786787,
                        30.7352527
                ]
        }
}
```

We are using **two** stages here in the aggregation pipeline, so to explain what each is actually doing:

First the [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) performs the query given the location provided here in GeoJSON format for comparison within the `"near"` option, and this is of course the primary constraint. The `"spherical"` option is generally required for `"2dsphere"` indexes, and that is the type of index you actually want for your data. The `"distanceField"` is the other mandatory argument, and it specifies the name of the property which will actually record the distance from the queried point for the location the "document" was matched on.

The other options are the parts that make this work for what you want to do here. Firstly there is the `"distanceMultiplier"`, which is actually "optional" here as it simply governs the value which will be output in the property specified by `"distanceField"`. The value we are using here will adjust the **meters** returned as the "distance" into **miles**, which is what you are generally looking at. This actually does not have any other impact on the rest of the options, but since the `"distanceField"` is mandatory, we want to show an *"expected"* numeric value.

The next option is the other main "filter" to mimic your [`$geoWithin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) statement. The `"maxDistance"` option sets an upper limit on "how far away" a matched location can be. In this case we give it `7` for the miles where we multiply by `1609.34` which is how many **meters** are in a **mile**. Note the `"distanceMultiplier"` has no effect on this number, so any "conversion" **must** be done here as well.

The final option here is the `"includeLocs"`, which is actually the most important option here aside from the distance constraint. This is the actual part that tells us the "location data" which was actually used for the "nearest match" from the array of locations contained in the document. What is defined here is of course the property which will be used to store this data in the documents returned from this pipeline stage. You can see the additional `"location"` property added to each document reflecting this.

So that pipeline stage has actually identified the matching `"location"` data, but this does not actually identify which array member was actually matched, explicitly. So in order to actually return the information for the specific array member we can use [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) for the comparison.

The operation of course is a simple comparison of the "matched location" to the actual "location" data of each array member. Since there will only ever be **one** match, you could alternately use things like [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) and [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to do the comparison and extract only the "single" result, but [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) is generally the most self explanatory operation that is easy to understand.

---

The whole point of the restriction on the **radius** can be demonstrated by a few short changes to the conditions. So if we move the location away slightly:

```
  { "$geoNear": {
    "near": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [76.7786787, 30.6352527]    // <-- different location
    },
    "spherical": true,
    "distanceField": "distance",
    "distanceMultiplier": 0.000621371,
    "maxDistance": 7 * 1609.34,
    "includeLocs": "location"
  }},
```

This is still within the **radius** as reported within the output as specified for `"distanceField"`:

```
 "distance" : 6.917030204982402,
```

But if you change that **radius** to be less than the reported number:

```
  { "$geoNear": {
    "near": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [76.7786787, 30.6352527]    // <-- different location
    },
    "spherical": true,
    "distanceField": "distance",
    "distanceMultiplier": 0.000621371,
    "maxDistance": 6.91 * 1609.34,      // <--- smaller radius
    "includeLocs": "location"
  }},
```

Then the query would return neither of the documents presented in the question. Thus you can see how this setting governs the same boundaries as is implemented with the [`$geoWithin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) query, and of course we can now identify the matched sub-document.

---

### Multiple matches

As a final note on the subject we can see how the `"includeLocs"` option can be used to identify the matching entry for a location within an array of a parent document. Whilst this should suit the use case here, the clear limitation is in matching **mutliple** locations within a range.

So "multiple" matches is simply beyond the scope of the [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) or other geospatial operations with MongoDB. An alternate case would be instead [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array content after the intial [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) and then the [`$geoWithin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) stage in order to "filter" those **multiple** matches:

```
User.aggregate([
  { "$geoNear": {
    "near": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [76.7786787, 30.7352527]
    },
    "spherical": true,
    "distanceField": "distance",
    "distanceMultiplier": 0.000621371,
    "maxDistance": 7 * 1609.34,
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$parking_space" },
  { "$match": {
    "parking_space.location": {
      "$geoWithin": {
        "$centerSphere": [
          [76.7786787, 30.7352527], 7 / 3963.2
        ]
      }
    }
  }}
],function(err,park_places) {
  // rest of your code.
})
```

It's probably better to actually use the [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) stage here, and we really just do the same thing without needing the `"includeLocs"` option. However if you really want to then there is nothing wrong with simply using the [`$geoWithin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) on either side of the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage:

```
User.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "parking_space.location": {
      "$geoWithin": {
        "$centerSphere": [
          [76.7786787, 30.7352527], 7 / 3963.2
        ]
      }
    }
  }}
  { "$unwind": "$parking_space" },
  { "$match": {
    "parking_space.location": {
      "$geoWithin": {
        "$centerSphere": [
          [76.7786787, 30.7352527], 7 / 3963.2
        ]
      }
    }
  }}
],function(err,park_places) {
  // rest of your code.
})
```

The reason this is okay is because whilst [`$geoWithin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) works most *"optimally"* when it can actually use the geospatial index defined on the collection, it actually **does not require** the index in order to return results.

Hence in either case after the "initial query" returns the "document" which contains *at least one* match for the condition, we simply [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array content and then apply the same constraints all over again to filter out those array entries, now as documents. If you want the "array" to be returned, then you can always [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) the elements back into array form.

By contrast the [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) pipeline stage **must** be used as the very first pipeline stage **only**. That is the only place it can use an index, and therefore it is not possible to use it at later stages. But of course the "nearest distance" information is probably useful to you and therefore worthwhile actually including within the query results and conditions.

Comment: Hey Thanks for helping me out but when I try to fetch result by GeoNear i got this error _geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"no geo indices for geoNear\_ otherwise it works fine with geoWithin.

Comment: @Priyanklohan That's exactly why the text of the answer talks about creating a `"2dsphere"` index and ensuring you actually get index usage in your query. So you really should be creating one if you don't have one. Index creation is actually linked from the operator documentation links provided in the answer.

Comment: I have defined "2dsphere" In my Schema Like this. 'User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {
    usernameField: 'email'
});
User.index({
    "parking_space.$.location": '2dsphere'
});
User.pre('save', function(next) {
    now = new Date();
    this.updated_at = now;
    next();
});`   maybe it is not creating index as you explained in your answer that $geoWitnin does not required Index.

Comment: @Priyanklohan `{ "parking_space.location": '2dsphere' }` I strongly encourage you to actually read the abundance of links to the documentation already provided. Also go into your shell and "drop" all indexes on the collection. Incorrectly defined indexes like what you have done need to be removed. Mongoose will create new indexes on the next application start.

Answer (score 1):

```
User.aggregate([
        {
            path: '$parking_space',
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        },
        { $geoNear: {
          near: { type: 'Point', 'parking_space.location.coordinates': [76.7786787, 30.7352527] },
          distanceField: 'dist',
          maxDistance: 7 / 3963.2,
          spherical: true
        } },
])
```