# MongoDB: Projecting/Searching for array entries of array entries

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to do a search as follows in Mongo:

```
db.getCollection('years').find({
  season: 2018,
}, {
  weeks: {
    $elemMatch: {
      number: 5,
      playerStats: {
        $elemMatch: {
            player: { $in: ['5b7f8e7ac8c0ef318f03ef1c'] }
        }
      }  
    }
  }
})
```

Its definitely not returning the correct results, so I'll describe what I'm trying to do:
I have a year document with a field called season of which I want only the season document that matches 2018. Within that there's an array of weeks and I only want the week designated with the number 5.  So far so good, I can do this query no problem. Each week document has a playerStats array which I want to filter by their ids, and this is where the problem is, when I run this query, I get one record back with an id and no other fields.  I'm new to Mongo so it's possible my design is wrong or my query, any suggestions?

EDIT: Expected result requested:

```
{
  season:  2018,
  weeks: [{
    number: 5,
    playerStats: [...these would be filtered by their player field]
    ]
  }]
}
```

Comment: can you also provide a sample of the data?

Comment: add the expected json output to the post too.

Comment: I think I found an answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229123/return-only-matched-sub-document-elements-within-a-nested-array