# Retrieve data from MongoDb by using Spring Boot according to specific criteria

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am new about spring boot and mongodb and I have a very simple question.

```
class A{
    private String x;
    private String y;
    @DBRef
    private List<B> listOfB;

     ...  getter ....
     ...  setter ....

}

class B{

     private String q;
     private boolean status;
}

Query query = new Query();

query.addCriteria(new Criteria("status").is(true));
query.addCriteria(new Criteria("listOfB.$status").is(true));
mongoOperations.find(query, A.class);
```

I want to retrieve A object with listOfB but listOfB only consists of the value of status = true from MongoDb with spring boot.

Comment: pls refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229123/return-only-matched-sub-document-elements-within-a-nested-array

Comment: Actually I am looking a java solution