# What is the Corresponding query for getting document/documents based on a key and a condition?

Tags: mongodb

Need to get the data inside a array/nested array in MongoDB.

Suppose my Collection is :

```
{"No" : 1, "Inner":[{"Created By":"A1","Updated By":"AA1"}]}
{"No" : 2, "Inner":[{"Created By":"A2","Updated By":"AA2"}]}
{"No" : 3, "Inner":[{"Created By":"A3","Updated By":"AA3"}]}
```

and so on...

I Need to find document where No = 3 and Created By = A6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return only matched sub-document elements within a nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229123/return-only-matched-sub-document-elements-within-a-nested-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question I think a compound query is what you are looking for:

```
db.collection.find( { "No": 3, "Inner.Created By": "A6" } )
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: What if I have multiple rows inside Inner in each record?

Comment: I believe you can use "Inner.<your row>.Created By", but I haven't tested this myself. Will you let me know if you get a chance?

Comment: As recommended by you, I am able to do the update, by giving the row index.

Comment: But what if I have array inside, another array and so on... let's assume for now, it goes for atleast 3 levels, is there any way I can update the particular element/whole array

Comment: I'd imagine you can continue with "." to reach array within an array, but this might be a good topic to ask a separate question so other people can provide answers

Comment: I am more inclined to use the array filters. I suppose "." won't help me. I will have multiple levels of array.