# mongo doesn't return the correct document

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document

```
   {
  "_id": ObjectId("6031dca77e510208f5d9cad5"),
  "userId": ObjectId("600b49554a19f1df7e7dee6e"),
  "resumes": [
    {
      "_id": "6031dca725f5b16515b3fde1",
      "pronouns": "They/Them",
      "name": "Jai",
      "contact": {
        "email": "jai.kirdatt@me.com",
        "phone": "2035690347"
      },
      "location": {
        "city": "Stamford",
        "state": "CT"
      },
      "resume_name": "test",
      "headline": "Full snack developer",
      "summary": "Passionate full snack developer",
      "links": {
        "dribble": "",
        "facebook": "",
        "github": "",
        "twitter": "",
        "website": ""
      },
      "experience": [],
      "talks": [],
      "licenses_and_certifications": [],
      "awards": [],
      "education": [],
      "side_projects": []
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("6031de2e25f5b16515b3fde2"),
      "pronouns": "new",
      "name": "Jai",
      "contact": {
        "email": "jai.kirdatt@me.com",
        "phone": "2035690347"
      },
      "location": {
        "city": "Stamford",
        "state": "CT"
      },
      "resume_name": "new",
      "headline": "new",
      "summary": "new",
      "links": {
        "dribble": "",
        "facebook": "",
        "github": "",
        "twitter": "",
        "website": ""
      },
      "experience": [],
      "talks": [],
      "licenses_and_certifications": [],
      "awards": [],
      "education": [],
      "side_projects": []
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my query

```
db.resumes.find({"resumes._id" : ObjectId("6031dca725f5b16515b3fde1")})
```

The above query returns all the documents when it should return one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36230475/3724716) answer your question?

Comment: Try this `db.resumes.find({"resumes" : ObjectId("6031dca725f5b16515b3fde1")})`

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan Thank you! The question you linked definitely helps. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return only matched sub-document elements within a nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229123/return-only-matched-sub-document-elements-within-a-nested-array)

Comment: Hi @Joe, Yes, ArunKumarMohan had sent the same question